# webservice with Qt

Tags: qt, web-services, server-side

I'm looking for a code to implement a Web Service with Qt (server side)
If you have any information I will appreciate

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use [libqxt](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtweb.html) to implement the server-side webservice.

If you want to use [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)-based webservices [this](https://github.com/vinipsmaker/tufao) might be more promissing.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a fantastic technique: [Qt in the Cloud with QWebClient](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/09/18/qt-in-the-cloud-with-qwebclient/). It really works very well under Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

[QttpServer](https://github.com/supamii/QttpServer) should work for a service requiring:

- List item
- Mongo (db)
- Redis (cache)
- JSON
- URL routes
- and leverages libuv (built for NodeJS).